# How to run a virtual environment python file from the outside?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Hay,
I have a virtual environment python file and i want to run it from the outside (by double clicking in the python file)
but it doesn't run. it only works when I run it in VS code.
what should I do?
I wish someone can help

Python version: 3.8.10

Windows: 7

Answer (score 0):

From what I tell, you have certain dependencies that your script requires that you have only installed inside of the venv, it will only run when it finds those packages otherwise it will throw an error and exit, that is why when you click on your python file it exits immediately. Eg:

I have a venv called 'web' where I make web applications, if I go to cmd and type:

```
C:\website> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Now, if I type:

```
C:\website> workon web
(web) C:\website> python main.py
Running at http://127.0.0.1:5000/
```

See, you have to activate your virtual env first to make it work, follow all these steps and it should run.

If you want to send this project/script as a standalone package, you might want to use [docker](https://www.docker.com/).

Comment: Thanks for replaying, yeah that is my problem. so i have tried subprocess in my code like this: `subprocess.run(["pipenv", "shell"]` and it opens the virtual environment but the rest of the code doesn't execute. so i just want a way that when i double click in the python file it runs without i have to active the virtual environment manually.

Comment: @AmmarAyman in code you need to activate the environment, so activate the environment using the subprocess